# Publish into Artifactory with self signed certificate

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Trying to publish go dependencies with `jfrog rt go-publish go --self=false --deps=ALL` and getting `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

I copied a .pem file into `~/.jfrog/security/`, didn't help. Not sure how to diagnose the problem.

Comment: jfrog version 1.24.1

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. I tired adding the cert to the .jfrog\security folder based on the loink below, but that doiesn't seem to work. Artifactory is on a Linus host with a self-signed certificate, The command is being run from a windows server. https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingSelf-signedSSLCertificates

Answer (score 0):

I added the .crt file to the .jfrog/security folder and it worked.